# AC blower intermittently refuses to shut off

Tags: hvac

After outside AC stopped, my blower continued to run. Control board has 6 flashes, which indicate "open rollout switch". please note furnace was not on in hot summer. When I cut off power the the blower/control board to reset. It started working for a few day, then the blower won't stop problem came back again. This happened to two separate units of my AC recently. Thanks for any help in advance.

https://www.copeland.com/documents/50a55-289-50a55-743-50a55-843-wiring-diagram-en-4278878.pdf

[image: 50A55-289-01]

Comment: do you have a schematic to look at, what is the thermostat model

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram and make/model for your air-handler/furnace please?